# Display popup on click with attribute text JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

Actually what I want to do is to display a text and make visible a popup(not an actual popup but with some CSS that overlays everything) with a close button.
The code is something like this

```
<h3>Hello World</h3> <a href="/hw.html" target="_blank" thecode="HWLD">Open</a>
<h3>Hello World - Part 2</h3> <a href="/hw-2.html" target="_blank" thecode="HWLD2">Open</a>
```

Now what I want to do is that when clicked the anchor it will display a popup(as I already said a div with the text overlaying all content) containing the text in thecode attribute.
Like when clicked the first link the hw.html will open in a new window and when user will come back to this window he will see the popup with the text "HWLD".

Comment: I just can't believe that 2 people up-voted this question!

Comment: @Josep it will be better if you share the answer(if you know).
StackOverflow is a community for asking codding related questions(and everybody has a right to upvote a question if he/she is also interested in that).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what StackOverflow is! Now, seriously, no one can share the answer, because this is not a question. This is you letting us know that you want to do something, but that you don't know how to do it. What you want to do can be done in a 1000000 different ways, and you were obviously too lazy to try to figure it out, so you decided to come here and try to get someone to do that for you. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and read about what to ask and what not to ask and maybe then you will understand why this is not an appropriate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML for the pop-up

```
<div id="popup"></div>
```

CSS for the pop-up

```
#popup {display:none; position:fixed; top:30%; left:50%; z-index:9999}
```

You can adjust the top, left, z-index according to you

jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(){
 $('#popup').html($(this).html());
$('#popup').show();
});
```

This is probably a simple version of the required implementation to give you the guidance, but hopefully you can improvise and improve upon this.

Comment: That is working but how to display the text within attribute thecode instead of .html

Comment: So you don't want to show the text in the pop-up? which attribute do you want to put it in?

Comment: If someone else need 
how to select attribute
 `$('.ppcode').html($(this).attr('tbecode'));`

Answer (score 0):

### HTML popup for your use

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

and then in your java script add that

```
$('#anyId').click(function(){
var html = "<p> my text....</P>"
$('#myDiv').html(html);
$('#myDiv').show();
});
```

Comment: this is only a part of the solution I already provided. Will need to do much more in it to make it work